# presume his place?

Tags: meaning

> After a century of modernization oriented toward the beacon that is
> Western democracy, the secular Turkish republic founded by Mustafa
> Kemal Ataturk may be crushed by the first politician to presume his
> place.
>
> — [*Time* magazine](http://time.com/collection/2017-time-100/4736338/recep-tayyip-erdogan/)

In this sentence, **presume his place** means someone who think himself or herself is eligible for that place takes that place? Is that correct? I'm so curious..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be a translation failure.

According with Cambridge Dictionary

**[presume](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/presume)**

> to believe something to be true because it is very likely, although
>   you are not certain

**[assume](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/assume)**

> 1. to accept something to be true without question or proof
> 2. to take or begin to have responsibility or control, sometimes without the right to do so, or to begin to have a characteristic

Notice that **presume** and **assume** are [synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/presume) in the first acception but NOT in the second.